# Is there a solution for fixing or bypassing an HTTPStatusException 403 error using Jsoup in Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, http, jsoup

The program I have is a webscraper that goes to multiple video game stat tracking websites and gathers stats for certain players whose names have been input into a google spreadsheet. The program is for personal use so I am satisfied with disabling certification verification and exposing myself to the risks associated with it. I am currently getting the following error upon running my code:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.jsoup.HttpStatusException: HTTP error 
fetching URL. Status=403, 
URL=https://overwatchtracker.com/profile/pc/global/ClaySymp-1875 
at 
org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection$Response.execute(HttpConnection.java:776)
at 
org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection$Response.execute(HttpConnection.java:722)
at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection.execute(HttpConnection.java:306)
at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection.get(HttpConnection.java:295)
at HtmlParser.main(HtmlParser.java:134)
```

My current code is:

```
`
import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Element;
import org.jsoup.select.Elements;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.security.cert.CertificateException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import javax.net.ssl.*;
import java.security.SecureRandom;
import java.security.cert.X509Certificate;

public class HtmlParser {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

     // Create a trust manager that does not validate certificate chains
      TrustManager[] trustAllCerts = new TrustManager[] { 
        new X509TrustManager() {
          public X509Certificate[] getAcceptedIssuers() { 
            return new X509Certificate[0]; 
          }


        @Override
        public void checkClientTrusted(X509Certificate[] arg0, String arg1) throws CertificateException
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
        @Override
        public void checkServerTrusted(X509Certificate[] arg0, String arg1) throws CertificateException
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
      }};

      // Ignore differences between hostnames
      HostnameVerifier hv = new HostnameVerifier() {

        @Override
        public boolean verify(String arg0, SSLSession arg1)
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return true;
        }
      };

      // Install the all-trusting trust manager
     try {
        SSLContext sc = SSLContext.getInstance("SSL");
        sc.init(null, trustAllCerts, new SecureRandom());
        HttpsURLConnection.setDefaultSSLSocketFactory(sc.getSocketFactory());
        HttpsURLConnection.setDefaultHostnameVerifier(hv);
} catch (Exception e) {}



    // ROCKET LEAGUE PLAYER NAME SETUP
    ArrayList<String> rlList = new ArrayList<String>();
    Document rlDoc = Jsoup.connect(
            "https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/e/2PACX-1vRGC6L6f9jAdqE3YsVLQRxlH3pHWj451XcxOaluQoWSJsZBwUiGeFmzzrogINy81Ng_Ic-y-wM5sPoC/pubhtml")
            .get();
    for (Element table : rlDoc.select("table.waffle")) {
        for (Element row : table.select("tr")) {
            Elements tds = row.select("td");
            if (tds.size() > 0) {
                rlList.add(tds.get(0).text());
            }
        }
    }

    // ROCKET LEAGUE STAT COLLECTION
    for (int i = 0; i < rlList.size(); i++) {
        String full = "";
        String url = "https://rocketleague.tracker.network/profile/xbox/" + rlList.get(i);
        Document rl = Jsoup.connect(url).get();
        System.out.println(rlList.get(i));
        for (Element table : rl.select("table.card-table.items")) {
            int j = 0;
            for (Element row : table.select("tr")) {
                Elements tds = row.select("td");
                if (tds.size() > 5) {
                    if (tds.get(1).text().substring(0, 6).equalsIgnoreCase("ranked")) {
                        String td2 = tds.get(2).text();
                        String td4 = tds.get(4).text();
                        if (td2.equals(""))
                            tds.get(2).html("N/A");
                        if (td4.equals(""))
                            tds.get(4).html("N/A");

                        if (j == 0) {
                            full = tds.get(1).text().substring(16) + " " + tds.get(2).text() + " "
                                    + tds.get(3).text() + " " + tds.get(4).text() + " " + tds.get(5).text();
                        } else if (j == 1) {
                            full = tds.get(1).text().substring(19) + " " + tds.get(2).text() + " "
                                    + tds.get(3).text() + " " + tds.get(4).text() + " " + tds.get(5).text();
                        } else if (j == 2) {
                            full = tds.get(1).text().substring(25) + " " + tds.get(2).text() + " "
                                    + tds.get(3).text() + " " + tds.get(4).text() + " " + tds.get(5).text();
                        } else if (j == 3) {
                            full = tds.get(1).text().substring(20) + " " + tds.get(2).text() + " "
                                    + tds.get(3).text() + " " + tds.get(4).text() + " " + tds.get(5).text();
                        }
                        System.out.println(full);
                        j++;
                    }

                }
            }
        }
        System.out.println("\n");
    }
    // END ROCKET LEAGUE

    // OVERWATCH PLAYER NAME SETUP
    ArrayList<String> owList = new ArrayList<String>();
    Document owDoc = Jsoup.connect(
            "https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/e/2PACX-1vSZ7qiTCaOniDQzn4nq0tLdT_pATKa7Y1k30CebIgoxxEd04PsRRc-K2LjfzD_rSrsREluLS4oKtAPn/pubhtml")
            .get();
    for (Element table : owDoc.select("table.waffle")) {
        for (Element row : table.select("tr")) {
            Elements tds = row.select("td");
            if (tds.size() > 0) {
                owList.add(tds.get(0).text());
            }
        }
    }

    // OVERWATCH STAT COLLECTION

    for (int i = 0; i < owList.size(); i++) {
        String url = "https://overwatchtracker.com/profile/pc/global/" + owList.get(i);
        System.out.println(owList.get(i));
        Document ow = Jsoup.connect(url).userAgent("Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/72.0.3626.121 Safari/537.36").get();
        Elements elements = ow.select("div.infobox-container");
        for (Element e : elements) {
            System.out.println(e.text());
        }
        System.out.println("\n");
    }

    // END OVERWATCH

    // FORTNITE PLAYER NAME SETUP
    ArrayList<String> fList = new ArrayList<String>();
    Document fDoc = Jsoup.connect(
            "https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/e/2PACX-1vQuZI5-dcO1vAzB_Yl-FWURT_tp2Wog7G2Xg8_2BDZRgPyGJFUDFh0w_ryIkgrcJ_U1ogFdez-R4ngj/pubhtml")
            .get();
    for (Element table : fDoc.select("table.waffle")) {
        for (Element row : table.select("tr")) {
            Elements tds = row.select("td");
            if (tds.size() > 0) {
                fList.add(tds.get(0).text());
            }
        }
    }

    // FORTNITE STAT COLLECTION

    for (int i = 0; i < fList.size(); i++) {
        String full = "";
        System.out.println(fList.get(i));
        Document f = Jsoup.connect("https://fortnitetracker.com/profile/pc/" + fList.get(i)).userAgent("Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/72.0.3626.121 Safari/537.36").get();
        Elements elements = f.select("div.trn-defstats.trn-defstats--width4");
        for (Element e : elements) {
            System.out.println(e.text());
        }

    }
    System.out.println("\n");
    // END FORTNITE
}
```

}

and the current full output I receive is:

```
EZJ7
Platinum I Division II N/A 657 (Top 33%) N/A 0 Win Streak: 6
Unranked Division I N/A 1,090 (Top 21%) N/A 0
Unranked Division I N/A 568 (Top 60%) N/A 0 Losing Streak: 5
Diamond II Division III N/A 1,062 (Top 25%) N/A 0


WombatWarfare11
Diamond III Division II N/A 957 (Top 4.2%) N/A 0
Champion II Division II ~3 1,311 (Top 6%) ~27 74
Diamond II Division II N/A 912 (Top 11%) N/A 0
Champion II Division I ~12 1,283 (Top 7%) ~25 17 Losing Streak: 3


BlueFlash19
Gold III Division IV N/A 621 (Top 42%) N/A 0 Losing Streak: 5
Diamond II Division II N/A 1,030 (Top 25%) N/A 0 Losing Streak: 6
Platinum II Division I N/A 696 (Top 35%) N/A 0 Losing Streak: 2
Diamond III Division III N/A 1,161 (Top 15%) N/A 0 Losing Streak: 3


ClaySymp-1875
Exception in thread "main" org.jsoup.HttpStatusException: HTTP error 
fetching URL. Status=403, 
URL=https://overwatchtracker.com/profile/pc/global/ClaySymp-1875
at 
org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection$Response.execute(HttpConnection.java:776)
at 
org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection$Response.execute(HttpConnection.java:722)
at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection.execute(HttpConnection.java:306)
at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection.get(HttpConnection.java:295)
at HtmlParser.main(HtmlParser.java:134)
```

Please feel free to call me out for anything I am doing wrong as I am fairly new to networking but I am looking for a solution to this type of error that isn’t as ghetto as my solutions for the self-signed certificates.

Comment: 403 is a forbidden code, so most likely you have to authenticate to the website prior to attempting to access the page. It is also possible the page is misspecified in your code, or that some parameter must be passed to the page.

Comment: @KevinO Can you elaborate on the authentication and parameter solutions?